# Add class to link when not active ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a navigation list using React, adding the activeClassName class to a link when it's active, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to add an 'inactive' class to links in the navigation that aren't active? Thanks in advance for any help.

```js
<ul className={styles.desktopLinks}>
  {this.products.map((value, key) => {
    return (
      <li key={key}>
        <Link to={value.to} activeClassName="__link-active">
          <FormattedMessage {...value.msg} />
        </Link>
      </li>
    );
  })}
</ul>
```

Comment: it doesn't seem like there's anything built in, can you not use the absence of activeClassName to achieve your goal?

Comment: No, inactive links need a class different from the active link to apply styling, and this only needs to happen when one link is active.

Comment: See my answer, i think you can get what you want with what you have

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add class to links using `className` property, and override it styles in `activeClassName`.

Comment: You can't use className in a <link> tag sadly

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul className={styles.desktopLinks}>
{this.products.map((value, key) => {
         let active = this.props.location.pathname.indexOf(value.to) > -1 ? true : false;
            return (
              <li key={key}>
                <Link to={value.to} activeClassName={active ? '__link-active' : '__link-inactive'}>
                  <FormattedMessage {...value.msg} />
                </Link>
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am getting a "Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected }" error on the : after !!active?

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a way to add a conditional? In my testing className doesn't work on <link>, but I'm very new to this.

Comment: @Hajji this will throw the error `boolean` not defined.

Comment: This is normal because I simulate the test, normally it must replace the boolean by the test active or not

Comment: exemple:
activeClassName={key==1 ? 'active' : 'incative'}

Comment: @HajjiTarik how would I get around the boolean undefined error with your code?

Comment: for exemple you have 
> link:inactive
> link:active
> link:inactive

you put
activeClassName={key==1 ? 'active' : 'incative'}

Answer (score 0):

As another way to achieve what you want, simply target it using the containing element and override the styles when active. In this case, you can add a class to the `li` (you can probably use `className` on the `Link` itself, but it's beside the point).

```
<li key={key} className="your-class">
  <Link to={value.to} activeClassName="__link-active">
    <FormattedMessage {...value.msg} />
  </Link>
</li>

.your-class a {
  // inactive styles here
}

.your-class a.__link-active {
  // override them here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the inactive links only need a class when another link is active

Comment: If it's only for styling purposes, then why? You can override all the styles when active, effectively doing the same thing. I get what you're saying but I don't think it's necessary.

Comment: Say all the nav links are read at the beginning, then when one is clicked it turns green, while the others turn blue. Does that make sense @aw04

Comment: So there's a third state when none are active that gets a different style?

Comment: Correct, as in the base styles

Comment: Ok, I think you need to make that more clear in the question. When you say 'inactive' most people take that to mean 'not active'

Comment: I think you will need to handle this case on a click event or something... so like literally what you said in comment, make them all start off one color, then once someone clicks one you can apply what i or others have said (i think that covers it)

Answer (score 0):

Write it like this:

```
<ul className={styles.desktopLinks}>
  {this.products.map((value, key) => {
    let isActive = this.props.location.pathname.indexOf(value.to) > -1 ? true : false;
    return (
      <li key={key}>
        <Link to={value.to} activeClassName={isActive ? "__link-active" : "">
          <FormattedMessage {...value.msg} />
        </Link>
      </li>
    );
  })}
</ul>
```

Or in place of `this.props.location.pathname` you can use this also `window.location.hash`.

Comment: It's returning a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined"?

Comment: use this: window.location.hash

Comment: Yes thank you, but this doesn't add an inactive class to the other list items that aren't active? <Link to={value.to} activeClassName={isActive ? "" : "__link-active"}>

Comment: It's working but only adding a class to the active link, I need to add a different class to the other links that aren't active at the same time

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a class called .nav-link and putting your original(a.k.a. non-active link) styles in there.